# Unable to start the Integration services for SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, windows-server, service-pack

Suddenly we are facing some errors in starting up the integration services.

From event viewer and ssms when we tried connecting we get below error message

*The SQL Server Integration Services 11.0 service failed to start due to the following error: 
This version of SQL Server Integration Services 11.0 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.*

Some info:- This is the mirror server where databases are in mirror state. We had some windows patching last night and after reboot started seeing these errors. Interestingly we had other servers also patched along with its principal, but did not witness the similar IS error out there and other servers.

Tried researching on this but unable to much details on the error posted.

Thanks, please suggest

Comment: What happens if you remove the patches that were installed last night?

Comment: @Nic, we cannot remove the patches as of now since they did not created the issue on Primary server

Comment: Are the versions (and patch level) of Windows, SQL Server Integration Services, and SQL Server the same with all servers?

Comment: @AntoineHernandez: Yes, they are all same. Verifying that was the first thing we did.

Comment: @BeginnerDBA you're looking at things that have changed. Removing the Windows patches from the server eliminates the change. That way you can see if it's something outside of those, otherwise you are just clutching at straws with guesswork.